# how to resolve error while redirecting from one page to another in android?

Tags: android, xml

I am not able to go to the page when i click on one button of my app. When i click on that button that java file has the XML layout which is i have written below

tutorial3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/IVDisplay" android:src="@drawable/back_abstract" android:layout_height="200dp"></ImageView>
    <Button android:text="Set Wallpaper" android:id="@+id/bSetWallpaper"        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="200dp"   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/IVimage1" android:src="@drawable/back_abstract" android:layout_height="125dp" android:padding="15dp"></ImageView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/IVimage2" android:src="@drawable/back_apple" android:layout_height="125dp" android:padding="15dp"></ImageView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/IVimage3" android:src="@drawable/back_bacon" android:layout_height="125dp" android:padding="15dp"></ImageView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/IVimage4" android:src="@drawable/back_cheese" android:layout_height="125dp" android:padding="15dp"></ImageView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/IVimage5" android:src="@drawable/back_rainbow" android:layout_height="125dp" android:padding="15dp"></ImageView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/IVimage6" android:src="@drawable/back_skull" android:layout_height="125dp" android:padding="15dp"></ImageView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/IVimage7" android:src="@drawable/back_skunk" android:layout_height="125dp" android:padding="15dp"></ImageView>            

</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>            
</LinearLayout>
```

My onClick code:

```
Button bTutorial3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tutorial3);
bTutorial3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent("com.cornboyz.thebasics.TUTORIALTHREE"));
    }
});
```

It shows me the following error:

> The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

Comment: where the problem here? show your logcat detail and activity where you define the button

Comment: that button is in main.xml file and then it uses startActivity to redirect to tutorialThree class which has layout tutorial3.xml

Comment: show me your button click action code

Comment: remove inverted comma "" from intent and set `.class` at the end

Comment: `The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.` Is no error message. Its just to inform the user that an error happened. Check your logcat and post the error that it contains.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent _intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext,"TUTORIALTHREE");
_intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(_intent);
```

please check your class to register in AndroidManifest.xml file like this class as activity for registration

Comment: still it not working and i have added my activity in manifest.

Comment: show your error yaar whenever get problem then show with the error so another can know where you exactly wrong please more about your code and error

Comment: what everything u say? where the error which you are getting?

Comment: i am not able to go to next page when i click on bTutorial3 button where the code is exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

It will surely work.
You need two changes in your code.
Firstly add this code in your tutorial here.

java file.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TUTORIALTHREE extends  Activity {
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

you can change your xml file name instead of main.xml file
e.g:  setContentView(R.layout.second);
second: add this code in your manifest file

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".your current activity page"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



<activity android:name=".TUTORIALTHREE"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```